# Whats the best way to asynchronously return a result (as a struct) that hasn't been fully "set up" (or processed) yet

Tags: c, asynchronous, concurrency, pthreads, threadpool

Alright, I honestly have tried looking up "Asynchronous Functions in C" (Results are for C# exclusively), but I get nothing for C. So I'm going to ask it here, but if there are better, already asked questions on StackExchange or what-have-you, please direct me to them.

So I'm teaching myself about concurrency and asynchronous functions and all that, so I'm attempting to create my own thread pool. So far, I'm still in the planning phase of it, and I'm trying to find a clear path to travel on, however I don't want a hand-out of code, I just want a nudge in the right direction (or else the exercise is pointless).

What would be the best way to asynchronously return from a function that isn't really "ready"? In that, it will return almost immediately, even if it's currently processing the task given by the user. The "task" is going to be a callback and arguments to fit the necessary pthread_t arguments needed, although I'll work on attributes later. The function returns a struct called "Result", which contains the void * return value and a byte (unsigned char)  called "ready" which will hold values 0 and 1. So while "Result" is not "ready", then the user shouldn't attempt to process the item yet. Then again, the "item" can be NULL if the user returns NULL, but "ready" lets the user know it finished.

```
struct Result {
    /// Determines whether or not it has been processed.
    unsigned char ready;
    /// The return type, NULL until ready.
    void *item;
};
```

The struct isn't really complete, but it's a basic prototype embodying what I'm attempting to do. This isn't really the issue here though, although let me know if its the wrong approach.

Next I have to actually process the thing, while not blocking until everything is finished. As I said, the function will create the Result, then asynchronously process it and return immediately (by returning this result). The problem is asynchronously processing. I was thinking of spawning another thread inside of the thread_pool, but I feel it's missing the point of a thread pool as it's not longer remaining simple.

<strike>Here's what I was thinking (which I've a feeling is grossly over-complicated). In the function add_task, spawn a new thread (Thread A) with a passed sub_process struct then return the non-processed but initialized result. In the spawned thread, it will also spawn another thread (see the problem? This is Thread B) with the original callback and arguments, join Thread A with Thread B to capture it's return value, which is then stored in the result's item member. Since the result will be pointing to the very same struct the user holds, it shouldn't be a problem</strike>.

<strike>My problem is that it spawns 2 threads instead of being able to do it in 1, so I'm wondering if I'm doing this wrong and complicating things.</strike>Is there a better way to do this? Does pthread's library have a function which will asynchronously does this for me? Anyway, the prototype Sub_Process struct is below.

```
/// Makes it easier than having to retype everything.
typedef void *(*thread_callback)(void *args);

struct Sub_Process {
    /// Result to be processed.
    Result *result;
    /// Thread callback to be processed
    thread_callback cb;
    /// Arguments to be passed to the callback
    void *args;
};
```

Am I doing it wrong? I've a feeling I'm missing the whole point of a Thread_Pool. Another question is, is there a way to spawn a thread that is created, but waiting and not doing anything? I was thinking of handling this by creating all of the threads by having them just wait in a processing function until called, but I've a feeling this is the wrong way to go about this.

To further elaborate, I'll also post some pseudocode of what I'm attempting [here](https://gist.github.com/theif519/49147ec40d5b5b335f38)

Notes: Was recommended I post this question here for an answer, so it's been copy and pasted, lemme know if there is any faulty editing.

Edit: No longer spawns another thread, instead calls callback directly, so the extra overhead of another thread shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I've glanced at your gist: I don't see any reason to use `temp_thread` in the `Process_Result` function (is it a typo and shoud it be `Process_Task` ?) You could just invoke the user callback instead of starting a new thread an joining. Also, you need to synchronize access to the `Result` struct.

Comment: You can simply create a global structure with a flag bit, set the flag to false, create a new thread to process the structure, while the main thread do something else, check, do something else, check , ... until it sees the flag true. Since the whole structure has only one writer, you don't have to wrong about the synchronizing.

Comment: @Xaqq Yeah, figured that out about there not being a need to have a Thread B, definitely saves me quite a bit of resources. 

What do you mean synchronizing access to Result? If only the user and the one thread that's going to be processing the result are going to be using it, will there be a need to do so? I suppose I can do so for safety however, just to be sure.

Comment: @Tim3880 I was always taught to never use Global Variables, hence I stray from them. Although that's what I was intending on doing, except with non-global scope, just the locality of the scope it's called from. 

I plan on implementing a function which allows the user to wait on the result, probably by joining with the thread currently processing it, to avoid busy waiting.

Comment: When you need handle multiple threads and processes, i don't think you can avoid global variable completely. What do you plan to do in your main thread when the "sub" thread processing your data?

Comment: Based on your updated gist: despites what @Tim3880 said, you still need to worry about synchronisation. Here is why: You are doing `process->result->item = process->cb(process->args);` then `process->result->ready = 1; ` The thing is, the compiler (or even the processor) is allowed to reorder those assigment, so if they are not protected the user thread could see `result->ready` equals to 1 *before* the `result->item` being set.

Comment: @Tim3880 It depends really. If the main thread doesn't really need to have it asynchronous, although it currently isn't implemented, it will join the thread processing it. However, if it's asynchronous and needs the return value somewhere further down the line, then the returned value, the Result will let the user know when it's ready. And as I stated, I'll implement a function that will allow the user to wait on a given result. I'm not certain as to how I'll pair the result with a given thread, but I could wrap each pthread in another struct which holds on to it.

Comment: @KyleStanly I recommend looking into `condition variables` to let the user wait on a task.

Comment: @Xaqq Will setting Result's ready member to be volatile help at all?

Comment: @KyleStanly No it wont. A simple solution (not sure how efficient it would be) would like this: Declare a global mutex. Tell your user to not use the `result->ready` field. Instead, provide an `int result_is_ready(Result *)` function. In this function, check the readyness while holding the mutex. In the `ProcessTask` function process the callback and store its result into a temporary. Lock the mutex, assign `result->ready` and `result->item`. Unlock the mutex. You can now safely access `result->item` as long as `result_is_ready` returned `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume it is your intention is that a thread will request the asychronous work to be performed, then go on to perform some different work itself until the point where it requires the result of the asynchronous operation in order to proceed.

In this case, you need a way for the requesting thread to stop and wait for the `Result` to be ready.  You can do this by embedding a mutex and condition variable pair inside the `Result`:

```
struct Result {
    /// Lock to protect contents of `Result`
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    /// Condition variable to signal result being ready
    pthread_cond_t cond;
    /// Determines whether or not it has been processed.
    unsigned char ready;
    /// The return type, NULL until ready.
    void *item;
};
```

When the requesting thread reaches the point that it requires the asynchronous result, it uses the condition variable:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&result->lock);
while (!result->ready)
    pthread_cond_wait(&result->cond, &result->lock);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&result->lock);
```

You can wrap this inside a function that waits for the result to be available, destroys the mutex and condition variable, frees the `Result` structure and returns the return value.

The corresponding code in the thread pool thread when the processing is finished would be:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&result->lock);
result->item = item;
result->ready = 1;
pthread_cond_signal(&result->cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&result->lock);
```

> Another question is, is there a way to spawn a thread that is created,
>   but waiting and not doing anything? I was thinking of handling this by
>   creating all of the threads by having them just wait in a processing
>   function until called, but I've a feeling this is the wrong way to go
>   about this.

No, you're on the right track here.  The mechanism to have the thread pool threads wait around for some work to be available is the same as the above - condition variables.

Comment: You might like to add to your answer, how the asynchronously running thread whould access the result's `ready` flag for setting it.

Comment: Thank all of you guys for the help, definitely will help me get on the right track, and I definitely learned quite a bit today.

Comment: Actually, bit of a question. I see you have the portion which obtains the async result attempt to acquire the lock before checking if result is ready. Here's my question, what if somehow the user requests the Result before the thread processing it can actually lock it? Then it would deadlock, waiting for the thread to process it to send the signal that it's ready.

Also, wouldn't it be impossible for the result to NOT be ready when it acquires the lock since the lock is only released when it is ready.

Comment: Nevermind, looked up what cond_wait did, didn't know it automatically unlocks the lock and blocks until signaled.

Comment: I do have a bit of a question on freeing the Result after obtaining the item from it. Would it be better practice to instead of just taking the Result, take a pointer to the Result struct so it can free and assign it to NULL, to prevent double-freeing? Since a Null Pointer Dereference is rather defined behavior, secretly freeing the Result struct after the function ends, at least to me, could lead to mistakes.

Comment: You could do that if you wanted to.  Personally I have never worried too much about setting pointers to `NULL` after freeing them, but I can see the argument for it.